# How to get content height of Activity?

Tags: android, height

I have an Activity with no actionbar, and try to get its height.

Tested on Nexus 7 2013 with resolution `1200x1920`;

Using DisplayMetrics:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Then the screenHeight is `1824`.
The different between real height (`1920`) vs. screenHeight is because of the status bar.

But when I check its root view:

```
final View root = findViewById(R.id.root);
root.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
    public void run() {
    Log.d("TAG", "Root @w=" + root.getWidth() + " @h=" + root.getHeight());
}});
```

And result of height is: `1774`.
Content height is smaller than screen height is because of the virtual key (BACK, HOME, SWITCH APP).

To sum up: `screen height = statusbar height (if have) + actionbar height (if have) + root content height + virtual key height (if have)`

So, if we get content height, do not rely on DisplayMetrics. I think get height from root content is the best solution.

Well, now is the real question: I want to get root content height immediately without delay (it means don't run in a Runnable). Any suggest?